# Hot water without hot water supply and electricity

Tags: water, hot-water

I have a tap in a room where I only have a cold water supply. Also, I don't have current electricity nearby. Is there any way to provide at least lukewarm water there?

Comment: Do you have access to the roof where you could put PVC tubing and let 
 the sun or outside temp warm it up?

Comment: carry some in with you in a thermos flask?    really some more detail would help us to make useful suggestions

Comment: Why don't you have electricity in that room?

Comment: @JACK: No, unfortunately I don't have access to the roof.

Comment: @Jasen: Indeed, I didn't give the detail, but I would have a long term solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a holding tank or a coil of supply line, hidden under the sink.

It wouldn't last long, it'd only be ambient temperature at best, and its recovery would probably be hours, but it would be above the incoming water temperature at least long enough to wash your hands without getting frostbite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Bosch makes mini hot water heaters that have a standard plug. You can run a heavy-duty extension cord to operate it with the proper amount of amps (they are listed on the cord heater and on new cords), but long term you should have an electric outlet installed by an electrician.

[https://www.amazon.com/Bosch-Electric-Mini-Tank-Heater-2-5-Gallon/dp/B0148O658Y/ref=asc_df_B0148O658Y/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=198079373928&hvpos=1o4&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10364721406833964669&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9006798&hvtargid=pla-319346703050&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0148O658Y)

Comment: If electricity is not nearby I would have thought the OP considered an extension lead...

Comment: he hasn't said if it's 12 feet or 12 miles to the nearest electricity.

Answer (score 0):

Propane is a portable fuel source that can power water heaters in remote locations. It may not be economically feasible day after day over long term use but it certainly does not require electricity and it certainly will provide *hot* water.

Alternatively, rooftop solar water heaters can generate electricity enough to heat water. I understand this requires a rooftop water tank and some solar panels.